# Python AST, ast.NodeTransformer ,TypeError: required field 'lineno' missing from stmt

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd be v. gratefull to learn something, usefull, as for now, I've been moving blindly.
so the problem lays in python's `ast.NodeTransformer`. I was wondering if one is able to add an function to existing class using this way, and not getting mad.

this is how I proceded so far.

```
import ast, inspect, cla # cla is a name of class to which we want to add a new function

klass = inspect.getsource(cla)
tree = ast.parse(klass)
st = '''def function(): return 1'''
Foo = ast.parse(st)

class AddFunc(ast.NodeTransformer):
      def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
          return node, node.body + Foo.body
          self.generic_visit(node)

inst = AddFunc()
stuff = i.visit(tree)

# now the trouble begins, a compiling..
co = compile(stuff, filename='<ast>', mode='exec')

# i get TypeError: required "lineno" missing from stmt
```

I have tried (unsuccesfully as you could probably guess) to handle this by using
ast library helper functions `ast.fix_missing_locations()`,
and `ast.copy_location()`, but in most cases I've ended up guessing or
facing `AttributeError` by tuple which is inside `AddFunc` class.
Have anybody some idea, how to manage this?

Answer (score 10):

kolko's answer is correct, in this instance, you need to return an AST node. `Foo` in this case is a module, and its body should be the statements constructing the function, which can simply be spliced into the class definition.

It helps to understand that `ast.NodeTransformer` is very particular:

- it calls the `visit` method by the specific class name, ignoring hierarchy
- it evaluates the return value with `isinstance(AST)` and `isinstance(list)`, anything else is ignored!

You may also get this error or the closely related "lineno missing from expr" even when you're using `ast.fix_missing_locations` to add location data.

If this happens, it's because your AST has an element that's not allowed in that place. Use `astunparse.dump` to carefully examine the structure. Within a module body, there can only be statements. Within a function def, there can only be statements. Then there are specific places that you can have an expression.

To solve this, write out the python you're expecting to generate, parse it, dump it and check it against what you're generating.

Answer (score 7):

I found answer in twitter:
https://twitter.com/mitsuhiko/status/91169383254200320
mitsuhiko: "TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from stmt" — no, what you actually mean is "tuple is not a statement'. #helpfulpython

You return here tuple, but u must return ast

```
class AddFunc(ast.NodeTransformer):
  def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
      node.body += Foo.body
      return node
```